# OPEN: Can mobile notification land on different app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Let's say that I have app A, can the backend code for app A send notification which directly land to app B?

An alternative way is to receive notification on A, and then fire a intent for app B but this could add to latency.

Answer (score 1):

You can register several apps at firebase console within your project and send push notification with single server key. Then you can subscribe apps to different topics or for dirrect push bind the FCM token to the A or B app. As well you can use deep link to fire intent from A to B.

Comment: Will does work when we don't app B. Let's say app B is very general app, like phone app for example?

Comment: @RupaMaheshwari For regular apps there is only one condition. App should be installed and launched at least once. System app will receive push & intent 
by default.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much informations about the context, but I think you can filter the notifications in your Backend. If the Backend have a certain type of notification, then you can decide to send that notification to the app A or the app B.

How to filter the notifications? It depends on your notification provider and the technologies you are using.

But in principle I think it is a good idea to create a filter based on the type of notification in your case.

Comment: App B is not owned by me